# Cannot disable query_cache_type in my.cnf

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, mysql-innodb-cluster

I am trying to disable the query_cache_type  in my mariadb pod in docker due to known performance issues with that and InnoDB. I have some current settings in a production server running on an rpm that have the following settings:

```
query_cache_limit=1048576
query_cache_size=1048576
query_cache_type=OFF
```

Yet when I try to mimic these settings on my new server, it defaults to having query_cache_type set to ON when I look at "show GLOBAL VARIABLES"

```
| query_cache_type                                       | ON
```

I have tried to look in the error logs and see now mention of the term query_cache_type. I also restarted the docker mariadb instance to refresh the database configs and it did not update. Is there anything I should check? Could it possibly be that I need to completely remove the database to have it start with the new configs? I would rather not manually change it as it *should* be grabbing the right configs from my.cnf.

Comment: Are those settings in the `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf`?

Comment: @RickJames, yes they are.

Comment: What version is the new server?  Recommend adding `query_cache_size=0`.

Comment: @RickJames version is 10.3.24

Comment: Hmmm -- I learned something.  (See my Answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Starting from MariaDB 10.1.7, query_cache_type is automatically set to ON if the server is started with the query_cache_size set to a non-zero (and non-default) value.

-- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/query-cache/

So, add (or change) this to the `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf`:

```
query_cache_size=0
```